# how to show jasper report in web page with parameter panel

Tags: java, html, jasper-reports

I need to display the jasper report in webpage with parameter panel. I searched a lot of materials online, but they don't work to me. So, could anyone help me to display my report in web-page with parameter panel?
the XML file for my report is as follow.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.1.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.1.0  -->
<!-- 2015-06-25T02:16:07 -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="Blank_A4_2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="f63b2357-ec93-4888-9301-cc151fdd7756">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="NewDataAdapter "/>
    <parameter name="startdate" class="java.sql.Date">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Please select start date]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="starttime" class="java.sql.Time">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Please select start time]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="enddate" class="java.sql.Date">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Please select end date]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="endtime" class="java.sql.Time">
        <parameterDescription><![CDATA[Please select end time]]></parameterDescription>
    </parameter>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT count(distinct ttc.vehicle_id) as vc,ttc.routeTag,ttc_routes.title,ttc.dateTime
FROM ttc
INNER JOIN ttc_routes ON ttc.routeTag = ttc_routes.routeTag
WHERE ttc.dateTime >= TIMESTAMP($P{startdate}, $P{starttime}) and ttc.dateTime <= TIMESTAMP($P{enddate}, $P{endtime})
GROUP BY ttc_routes.title
order by vc desc
limit 10]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="vc" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <field name="routeTag" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="title" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="dateTime" class="java.sql.Timestamp">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="252" splitType="Stretch">
            <barChart>
                <chart evaluationTime="Report">
                    <reportElement x="227" y="52" width="200" height="200" uuid="ba244296-4247-4400-b20b-110dc34fa405"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA["SERIES 1"]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{title}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{vc}]]></valueExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot>
                    <plot/>
                    <itemLabel/>
                    <categoryAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </categoryAxisFormat>
                    <valueAxisFormat>
                        <axisFormat/>
                    </valueAxisFormat>
                </barPlot>
            </barChart>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="35" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="61" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band height="45" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: what do you mean, "display my report in web-page with parameter panel?"

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I just created the report, but meet another problem. May be you could help me on that side?

Comment: what is the another problem?